# Get API endpoints/schema/parameters without Documentation

Tags: api, php-curl

This question has been asked before, but all of the answers were incomplete or negative.

Although in none of them anyone said that they already have access to the API, which I do.

I got my token and a few endpoints from the developer tools in Chrome and managed to make some successful calls (guessing/trial and error).

There is no documentation for the API and nothing can't be found over the internet or on websites with public API's (it hasn't been created yet).

I am using cURL in PHP to make the calls and I have tried all sorts of calls to get some positive responses, but I only get errors like Forbidden/Not allowed. (Also tried with Postman - but I have almost no experience with it)

So, my question is: Is there any way to fetch the endpoints or somehow get a list of them? I'm not very familiar with API but having access already I think there must be a possibility, like pinging the address somehow and get them in response (more like a sitemap.xml)

**Edit**: Added some code I'm currently using

```
$header = array();
$header[] = "token: ##########################";
$header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$state_ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.domain.com/v3/messages.php");
curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$data = curl_exec ($state_ch);
```

Other Url's I found:

https://api.domain.com/data/partner-preferences.php

https://api.domain.com/v3/notifications.php

https://api.domain.com/version.php

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is: Is there any way to fetch the endpoints or somehow get a list of them?

**No, there is not.**

Not only you need to know the endpoints but also which parameters have to be passed (if any) in the URL and which data have to be sent (and in which format) for PUT and POST requests.

**You need the API documentation from the provider of the web service.**

Comment: As I mentioned already, the API documentation doesn't exist. And I can't get in contact with whoever made the API

Comment: @Carje what I mean is that if you don't have the documentation then you have no way to use the API.